# Prevent Pandas read_csv from truncating full timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas 0.11 on Mac OS X. I'm trying to import a csv file with pandas `read_csv`, one of the columns in the file is the full timestamp, with values like:

```
fullts
1374087067.357464
1374087067.256206
1374087067.158231
1374087067.074162
```

I'm interested in getting the time difference between the subsequent timestamps, so I import it specifying the `dtype`:

```
    data = read_csv(fn, dtype={'fullts': float64})
```

however, pandas seem to truncate the number to its integer part:

```
    data.fullts.head(4)
```

yields:

```
1374087067
1374087067
1374087067
1374087067
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Added: tried using `pd.to_datetime` as suggested, and get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-37ed0da45608> in <module>()
---> 1 pd.to_datetime(sd1.fullts)

/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/tools.pyc in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, utc, box, format)
    102         values = arg.values
    103         if not com.is_datetime64_dtype(values):
--> 104             values = _convert_f(values)
    105         return Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    106     elif isinstance(arg, (np.ndarray, list)):

/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/tools.pyc in _convert_f(arg)
     84             else:
     85                 result = tslib.array_to_datetime(arg, raise_=errors == 'raise',
---> 86                                                  utc=utc, dayfirst=dayfirst)
     87             if com.is_datetime64_dtype(result) and box:
     88                 result = DatetimeIndex(result, tz='utc' if utc else None)
/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/pandas/tslib.so in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas/tslib.c:15411)()

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: It works fine in my computer, which pandas version are you using?

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.11 with anaconda python on MAC OS X Lion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the dtype when reading from csv (it should use float64 by default).

In pandas 0.12 you can then covert columns of integers or floats (of epoch times) into pandas Timestamps using the unit argument of [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
         fullts
0  1.374087e+09
1  1.374087e+09
2  1.374087e+09
3  1.374087e+09

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(df.fullts)  # default unit is ns
Out[12]:
0   1970-01-01 00:00:01.374087067
1   1970-01-01 00:00:01.374087067
2   1970-01-01 00:00:01.374087067
3   1970-01-01 00:00:01.374087067
Name: fullts, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [13]: pd.to_datetime(df.fullts, unit='s')
Out[13]:
0   2013-07-17 18:51:07.357464
1   2013-07-17 18:51:07.256206
2   2013-07-17 18:51:07.158231
3   2013-07-17 18:51:07.074162
Name: fullts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Where the docstring state:

> `unit` : unit of the arg `(D,s,ms,us,ns)` denote the unit in epoch
>                    (e.g. a unix timestamp), which is an integer/float number

Comment: hey Andy,thanks for the answer. do you think the issue may be that I have Pandas 0.11 installed?

Comment: @Fra in 0.11 this doesn't take float values (but I think it takes ints, so either multiply to make it a nanosecond int or wait for 0.12 - out v soon :) )